# How to catch the response of a web push

Tags: push-notification, web-push

I'm using this library:
https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push/ and can successfully send a push with:

```
webPush.sendNotification(req.body.endpoint, {
  TTL: req.body.ttl,
  payload: req.body.payload,
  userPublicKey: req.body.key,
  userAuth: req.body.authSecret,
})
```

However, when I try to chain `.then` or `.catch` to it, I get nothing, empty strings. My goal is to be able to get the actual response from the GCM/Firefox server on whether the push was successful or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The promise returned by `sendNotification` will be resolved when there are no errors, will be rejected otherwise.

So if you are in the `then` branch, the push was successful. If you are in the `catch` branch, it wasn't.